# PostgreSQL - usar retorno customizado do select em loop

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql

Eu tenho uma função que faz um select como esse:

```
SELECT a.nome, b.email into nome, email FROM tabela1 a
INNER JOIN tabela2 b ON b.fk = a.fk
```

Tem alguma forma de criar uma "tabela temporária" que eu possa armazenar temporariamente os vários possíveis retornos dessa função e usar eles dentro de um laço como o a seguir?

```
LOOP
    --faz alguma coisa as variáveis nome e email
END LOOP
```

Edit - problema resolvido, solução nas respostas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
FOR nome, email IN 
(SELECT a.nome, b.email into nome, email FROM tabela1 a
INNER JOIN tabela2 b ON b.fk = a.fk)
LOOP
-- faz alguma coisa com as variáveis nome e email
END LOOP
```